# bootstrap row is not working

Tags: html, rows

[Bootstrap row col-md-4 not working properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wQui.png)
 Please help me with moving the last row up inline with the rest of the rows. Thank you! It was fine yesterday so I don't know what it can be since I haven't touched my code since then.

I really appreciate the help!

```css
/*WHY*/

#why {
 padding:5rem 0;
 background-color:#f6f6f6;
}

#why hr {
 width:30%;
}

#why .fa {
 color:#be2835;
 padding:15px 0;
}
```

```html
     <section id="why">
      <div class="container text-xs-center">
       
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn">
         <h2>Why work with us?</h2>
         <hr>
         <p>Because we are best at what we do!</p>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
         <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i>
         <h3>Customer Satisfaction</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
          <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-3x fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Instant Results</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
          <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x"></i>
          <h3>Award Winning Service</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
         </div>
        </div> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: You have fa 3x written twice in the second last row anyway... probably irrelevant to your problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the three `<div>`s with class `col-md-4` to be in the same row, all you have to do is remove the extra `<div class="row">` elements, along with their closing tags. So the html would look like this:

```
<section id="why">
    <div class="container text-xs-center">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeIn">
                <h2>Why work with us?</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Because we are best at what we do!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i>
                <h3>Customer Satisfaction</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-3x fa-3x"></i>
                <h3>Instant Results</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-3x"></i>
                <h3>Award Winning Service</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, I really appreciate that!